# Correct docker-compose syntax for sqlite volume

Tags: sqlite, docker-compose

I've been having a hard time finding the exact syntax I need for a docker-compose file after looking through the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

I'm building a small Flask webapp with a sqlite backend. I'm going to deploy the webapp in a Docker container and keep the sqlite db in a persistent volume.

I've already created the sqlite volume, called `app-sqlite`. The basic folder structure of my app is this:

```
/app
    app.py
    /db
        app.db
```

How do I format the docker-compose file so that it contains what it needs to for the container to connect with the `app.db`? Any variation I attempt is a nonstarter.